# What's the best way for an angular controller to alter an ancestor HTML element?

Tags: angularjs

I have an Angular controller which lives in a portion of the page however that application needs to get access to an HTML element that lives above it.

The best way to imagine the problem is that you have an embedded video which wants to request to be made full view-port:

```
<html ng-app="videoApp">

  <body>

    <div>
      Other stuff that doesn't relate to the video player...
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="videoCtrl">
      ... stuff relating to the video controller
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

The exact problem is that the `videoCtrl` needs to be able to add a class to the body class such that it can switch the page layout to being full-page and dominated by the video.

*Desired outcome, status of video app adds a "full-page" class to body tag:*

```
<body ng-class="video.fullPage ? 'full-page', : ''">
```

### What's would be the correct way for the video to add a class to an ancestor tag?

Under normal circumstances where the element we want to manipulate lies inside the controller that's doing the manipulation we can bind elements to variables in the scope:

```
<body> <!-- the videoCtrl scope is not available to <body> -->
  <div ng-controller="videoCtrl">
    <div ng-class="video.fullPage ? 'fullPage' : ''"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

However the body tag is not contained within the scope of the video controller and so has no access to the variables in its scope so we can't bind to them.

We could always reach out directly and change the class on the body using dom manipulation but that's not very *Angular*. What is the correct pattern for the video controller to alter the class of the body tag?

Answer (score 1):

To meet a very similar requirement, I used Angular events.  From the controller, `$broadcast` an event on `$rootScope`.  Then have some sort of screen layout controller handle the event and toggle the possible screen configurations.

So:

**child controller:**

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('layout-action', { configuration: 'video' });
```

**layout controller:**

```
$scope.$on('layout-action', function(event, args) {

    if (args.configuration == 'video') {

        $scope.showVideo = true;
    }
});
```

**html:**

```
<body ng-class="{'full-page': showVideo}">
```

*Note: this does slightly tie the child functionality to another part of the layout.  However, perhaps try to generalize the video layout. For example, maybe you want a `full screen` mode instead.

Comment: Thank you. I like this a lot and was thinking about events - they feel like they have the right decoupling to be the right solution. However I do wonder - if you have that parent scope there anyway, why not just have a variable on it that you alter directly? Feels smelly but I'm not sure why...

Comment: Because usually, we strive for components that do not depend on where they are placed on the page.  You might want to move the child controller to another place on the page.  Events allow you the freedom to more the component anywhere inside the `ng-app`.

Answer (score 1):

If `ng-app="videoApp"` is the only parent, you could also do something on the button that would trigger the full-page class like this:

```
<body ng-class="{'full-page': showVideo}">
  <div ng-controller="videoCtrl">
    <button ng-click="$parent.showVideo = !$parent.showVideo">I'm in the video controller!</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

In this case i'm just toggling showVideo to true or false. But like Davin said, this may not be as nice because it depends more on where it sits in the app.
See this plunkr for an example http://plnkr.co/edit/UxtA0YvCUckofAflsy9G

Comment: Thanks for putting that together Austin. It's one of the ways that I was thinking but as @Davin Tryon pointed out it assumes the controllers are definitely nested. I'm not necessarily sure that this would be unreasonable though here...